# Javascript link in table stay selected on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with links on each row, the links are javascript link and perform an AJAX query when clicked. I want the row for the selected link to stay highlighted when the link is clicked.

My current code will keep the row highlighted if the row is clicked but not if the link in the row is clicked.

```
<table class="table table-hover unpadded" id="mashed_tab">
    <tbody class="mashed_body">
        <?php
            foreach($linked as $link)
            {
                echo '<tr class="mashed_row">';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td class="linked-title dark unpadded"><div class="cell_link">';
                echo '<a href="javascript:;" id="linksplode" link_id="'.$link['linkid'].'">'.$link['keywords'].'</a></div></td>';
                echo '<td class="small-cell"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

tr.mashed_row i.fa-arrow-right {
    display:none;
}
tr.mashed_row:hover i.fa-arrow-right {
    display:block;
}

.mashed_body tr.selected {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("tbody tr").click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
```

Script for processing link:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.mashed_row a').click(function () {
            var link_id = $(this).attr('link_id');

         $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                   url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/explode_link',
                   data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', link_id},
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success : function(data) {
                       if(data){
                           var len = data.length;
                           var txt = "";
                           if(len > 0){
                               for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                                   if(data[i].title){
txt += "<tr><td class='linked-title dark unpadded'>"+data[i].title+"</td><td class='text-left'><span id='article_source' class='label label-primary'>"+data[i].name+"</span></td></tr>";
                                       }
                                    }
                               }
                               if(txt != ""){
                                   $("#xarticletab").html("");
                                   $("#xarticletab").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Probably because there is another click handler for those links that is preventing event propagation. Need to see handler code for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below mentioned code worked for me. Hope this helps your case also.

Get the hyperlink type elements in a row of your table and add class to it which will highlight the background. Also remove the previous selected rows if that is your requirement.

Reference : Add a class and removing a class to an element is java script :

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp

Searching elements using Jquery selector :

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

My Code :
Js :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     attachEvents();
  });

  function attachEvents() {

    $('table tr a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('highlightBackground');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlightBackground') ; 

   }); 
};
```

Html :

```
<style>

.highlightBackground
{
  background-color : red; 
}

</style>


<table>
<th> LinkColumn</th>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </th>
<th>Non Link Column</th>

<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
        <a href="#">Click</a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"> Row1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
        <a href="#">Click</a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"> Row2 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually, this is not working. When I click on a the next link, the old row stays highlighted.

Comment: This is working for me. Could on share your fiddle code or paste it here

Comment: Have tried the code from your Ques statement : $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("highlightBackground");. This also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try $("a").click( $(this.parent()).addClass('selected').sibilings().removeClass("selected");

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: That did not work. I receive error "TypeError: this.parent is not a function".

Comment: Sorry my bad..it should be $(this).parent().

Comment: $(this).parent().addClass('selected');$(this).parent().sibilings().removeClass('selected');